# Add CSS progress bar width from a ng array - Angular Ionic 3

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework, progress-bar, ionic3

I was trying to add width to my progress bar which was created using bootstrap 3 and width should bind from an angular array

```
      <ion-col col-12 *ngFor="let item of items">

        <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" 
                    width ="{{item.width}} + '%' "</div>

        </div>

      </ion-col>
```

but this didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Then I found out this way and it worked !

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'width': item.width + '%' }"
```